# avro-tools-1.11.1.jar causes NoClassDefFoundError in my existing program

Tags: java, jar, avro, avro-tools

I have a war file A that has multiple jar files - some developed by us and some 3rd party ones. This has been there for a long time and is working fine.
Now, I recently added Avro-1.11.1.jar and Avro-tools-1.11.1.jar as we need some specific Avro related functionality.

But when I copy the above 2 jars to the war file, my program does not even start up. I see the following error:

```
SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal A child container failed during start
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jersey/server/impl/application/DeferredResourceConfig
```

I looked up all the jars in the war file. None of them have the above mentioned class that is reported as not found. (Avro-tools jar has a folder com/sun/jersey. But no server folder inside that)

I don't know what exactly in my program is even calling the above class as I don't see this error when I don't add the Avro jars mentioned above.

I also tried using the above Avro jars (avro-1.11.1.jar and avro-tools-1.11.1.jar) with an older versions of my program war and that works. No such issues at startup and the functionality I need works too.

It happens when I add the Avro jars to the latest version of my program war.

Any inputs on this issue. please suggest.

Thanks,
Om